# How can I drop packets matching the source URL

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I want to block all incoming tcp packets that contain some string in the source URL. for example, I want to block all packages where the source url contains "facebook.com".

Using the commands below, I can block any package (input, output, forward) that contains the string "facebook.com". The problem is if the string "facebook.com" is inside the html body of the packet, this will be blocked as well.
    # iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP
    # iptables -A OUTPUT -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP
    # iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -m string --algo bm --string "facebook.com" -j DROP

There is a easy way to match the string only in the source URL of the packet?

Comment: Not sure wether you can investigate this layer this deep, does it help to match `--string "Host: facebook.com"` (from HTTP request header)?

Comment: it works for some sites (like www.ku.edu), but it don't works from facebook :'(

Comment: Ok then I have another comment. IPtables is not the right tool for what you try to do. It is not a firewalls job to investigate this part of the traffic. What you need is a proxy server with content-filtering. Like Squid+Dansguardian

Comment: Unless I grossly misinterprete your wording (_"tcp packets that contain some string in the source URL"_) it seems that you do not understand TCP or firewalls. TCP (or IP for that matter) does not contain URLs, these are part of another protocol (such as HTTP) layered on top. From the perspective of TCP, URLs are part of the payload (which is an opaque blob).

Comment: Not all TCP packets have a URL or URI related to them. You are looking for filtering above the TCP level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a easy way to match the string only in the source URL of the
>   packet?
>
> it works for some sites (like www.ku.edu), but it don't works from
>   facebook :'(

Note that Facebook uses SSL so you're not going to have anything to string match in the packets (they'll be encrypted).  It probably works for ku.edu because it's HTTP traffic and not HTTPS.  To do what you want with IP tables, you would need to filter based on IP address or host name.  You could try something like `-j DROP -d facebook.com`.

Agreed with DanFromGermany that iptables is not the right tool for the job.  Blocking based on IP address or host name might initially work but it could break and would be difficult to maintain.  I believe that the DNS name is resolved to an IP address when the rule set is loaded by iptables.  This means that if Facebook changes its external IP (perhaps due to a failover or load issue) or has more than one IP it won't work.

Comment: Yes, the big problem I have is this. When facebook changes its IP address the iptables rule will not have effect, because iptables resolve the address only in the moment of insertion of the rule.

Comment: Again I really believe that iptables is not the right tool for the job and what I'm about to suggest is extremely hackish... but another possible way to block facebook is to block all DNS requests that match facebook.com.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, according to the [MAN](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) page, the string filter accepts "from" and "to" parameters, limiting the range of bytes searched. Assuming there's nothing special about the packets passing through this machine (i.e. tunneling or any special headers), you can specify "from" to be 40 bytes (20 bytes IP header, 20 bytes tcp header), and "to" to be around 80 (I suggest looking at some sample packets to verify these numbers)

Second, to minimize false positives, try blocking request packets that contain facebook as the HTTP host (i.e. "Host: facebook.com" or 'Host: www.facebook.com"), I'd also limit it to tcp ("-p tcp") and port 80. The result is something like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --from 40 --to 80 --string "Host: facebook.com" -j DROP
```

Note that I'm currently on a windows machine and can't verify the syntax.

In any case, this won't help against HTTPS sessions. If you need to block HTTPS sessions with facebook using iptables, you'll have to use `-j DROP -d facebook.com` like John suggested. Naturally, that still won't work against someone accessing facebook over HTTPS through a proxy or a tunnel, but it should be enough to block most users.